# How can Tax Labels be Enabled for Prices Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price

I want to add a label for VAT on product prices on a store. I was going to do it simply with css rule like below:

```
.price-final_price.tax .price::after {content: "ex. vat"; font-size: small;}
```

However i can see the below code within 'vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml' that seems to be ready for  labels:

```
    <?php echo($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
```

However i cannot find how to set the labels so they show on the frontend?